# Am reading data from database to jtable which has a custom AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

Am reading database data into jtable using  two dimensional ArrayList. I use the Result set to iterate through the data in the database and then save the results into the AbstractTableModel which later updates the JTable. The problem is that only the last row is read and appears in the results the times the number of rows that are in the database, only duplicating the last row, instead of populating  each row . Kindly advise the logic behind.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
ArrayList<String> data4 ;
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data5;
 try {
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
 } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(SowInformation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(SowInformation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(SowInformation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
  PreparedStatement   ps=null;
 Connection c = null; 
 ResultSet rs =null;

 data4 =new ArrayList<String>();
data5 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
  try {
 c = DriverManager.getConnection(query);
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(SowInformation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
 } 
try {

 String query ="SELECT * FROM sow_info_3" ;
 ps = c.prepareStatement(query);

 rs=ps.executeQuery();
int i1=0, a =0,b=1, c1=2,  d =3, e= 4, f =5,  g =6,  h=7,  i=8, j=9,k=10;        
 while(rs.next()){
 data4.add(a, rs.getString("sow_info_id"));
 data4.add(b, rs.getString("sow_name"));
 data4.add(c1,rs.getString("sow_colour"));
 data4.add(d,rs.getString("sow_weight_kgs"));
 data4.add(e,rs.getString("sow_date_of_birth"));
 data4.add(f, rs.getString("sow_breed"));
 data4.add(g, rs.getString("sow_tag_number"));
 data4.add(h, rs.getString("sow_housing_type"));
 data4.add(i, rs.getString("sow_paddock_name"));
 data4.add(j, rs.getString("sow_transfer_status"));

 data4.add(k,rs.getString("sow_on_farm_by_status"));



data5.add(i1, data4); 
 }





 model = new MyTableModel(data5, column1);
jTable1.setModel(model);

} catch (SQLException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(SowInformation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }

 try {
 c.close();
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(SowInformation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }


    }
```

Comment: If you need to post an image, please post a link to it, and we'll likely be able to load it into your question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the same data4 ArrayList multiple times to the data4 List of List, and this can make it look like you're only reading one row of data. To solve this you need to create a new data4 ArrayList, the list that appears to hold each individual row of data, **inside** of the while loop.'

so:

```
while(rs.next()) {
   data4 = new ArrayList<String>();
   data4.add(...);
   // ... etc
}
```

Your code also appears to run afoul of Swing threading rules as your database interactions should all be done in a background thread.

Comment: @AugustineBazirake: if your database access takes any time to complete, it will completely lock the Swing event thread, rendering your GUI frozen. For that reason, database and in fact any I/O code should be done in a background thread. For details, please read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: thanks so much for this wonderful piece of information. Truth be told am new to java programming and in fact am working on my first project but trust me, your advise is very exciting and my prayer is that we keep in support.